# compile an android-x86 kernel -- /bin/sh: 1 cd : can't cd to

Tags: compilation, android-x86

I am trying to compile the kernel android-x86 ( ics-x86 branches )
I followed this tutorial(1) , but I also paid attention to those link(2)

(1) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-x86/x5aBNnK4Ols

(2) http://www.android-x86.org/documents/customizekernel

when I enter the terminal with this command (1)

**$ make -C kernel O=/work/config/.config xconfig**

I get this :

**make: Entering directory '/home/base3/work/a_source/kernel'
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /work/config/.config
Makefile:121: *** output directory "/work/config/.config" does not exist.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/home/base3/work/a_source/kernel'**

If I do (2)

**$ make -C kernel O=$OUT/obj/kernel ARCH=x86 menuconfig**

I get :

**make: Entering directory '/home/base3/work/a_source/kernel'
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/base3/work/a_source/out/target/product/generic_x86/obj/kernel
Makefile:121: *** output directory "/home/base3/work/a_source/out/target/product/generic_x86/obj/kernel" does not exist.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/home/base3/work/a_source/kernel'**

I am in Debian jessie x86-64 , and I want to compile the android kernel to install on a notebook . Android (ics-x86) does not recognize my sata hdd ( SIS chipset )

please do not tell me to use another version of android

I would be very grateful for any hint that would make me go ahead

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can get past this phase using ubuntu 14.04 lts. Using debian jessie, I did not get it, because it made several errors

I used the command in ubuntu:

**$Make -C kernel O=$OUT/obj/kernel ARCH=x86 xconfig**